# Use of ivar in block returned to other object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have found a crash in an iPhone application with target iOS 4 that changes depending on the type of build.

The debugger is giving me nothing much to go on, it stops at

```
 UIViewController *result = [self factory](self);
```

with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. `self` is a class inheriting from NSObject (shown below as NSObjectInheritor). Zombies are enabled. I've tried changing method `factory` three ways with the following results.

This crashes in both debug and ad hoc builds...

```
- (FactoryMethod) factory;
{
    return [^ UIViewController * (NSObjectInheritor *newThing)
    {
      return [[ViewControllerClass alloc] initWithStuff:(boolValue ? foo : bar)];
    } autorelease];
}
```

This works in debug builds but crashes in ad hoc...

```
- (FactoryMethod) factory;
{
  return [^ UIViewController * (NSObjectInheritor *newThing)
  {
    if(boolValue)
    {
      return [[ViewControllerClass alloc] initWithStuff:foo];
    }
    else
    {
      return [[ViewControllerClass alloc] initWithStuff:bar];
    }
  } autorelease];
}
```

This works in both debug and ad hoc but is very ugly and redundant:

```
- (FactoryMethod) factory;
{
  if(boolValue)
  {
    return [^ UIViewController * (NSObjectInheritor *newThing)
    {
      return [[ViewControllerClass alloc] initWithStuff:foo];
    } autorelease];
  }
  else
  {
    return [^ UIViewController * (NSObjectInheritor *newThing)
    {
      return [[[ViewControllerClass alloc] initWithStuff:bar];
    } autorelease];
  }
}
```

My theory is that `boolValue` becomes inaccessible at the time the returned block is executed. It is

```
@interface SubclassOfNSObjectInheritor : NSObjectInheritor
{
  BOOL boolValue;
}

@property (readonly) BOOL boolValue;
```

(`YES` or `NO` assigned in SubclassOfNSObjectInheritor's init of course) and

```
@synthesize boolValue;
```

in SubclassOfNSObjectInheritor's implementation.

The final questions are - is my theory about what is wrong correct? Is the third way of doing it - noted as working in ad hoc and debug builds - safe? What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is twofold, first you are overreleasing your block and second, blocks are created on the stack, which is going away when your method returns (you're basically returning a pointer into the previously destroyed stack frame).

Instead, copy the block and auto release it before returning. You can do this in the objective-c way with a `copy` message, your you can call the `Block_copy()` function.

Your crashing in various configurations is pure happenstance. So, to fix one of your implementations:

```
- (FactoryMethod) factory;
{
  return [[^(NSObjectInheritor *newThing)
  {
    if(boolValue)
    {
      return [[ViewControllerClass alloc] initWithStuff:foo];
    }
    else
    {
      return [[ViewControllerClass alloc] initWithStuff:bar];
    }
  } copy] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Nice answer.   Note also that "Build and Analyze" should have caught this particular error.  If it did not, please file a bug.

Comment: Thank you - the analyzer does not complain, so will log the bug. Adding copy resolves the problem.